# Illegal string offset error in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am sending these objects to server to fetch the record and save it. but it is giving me the below given error

```
array(3) {
[0]=>
array(1) {
    ["answer"]=>
    string(218) "{"id":"19","question_id":"10","answer_text":"Please note that we also maintain you:",  
"iscorrect":"1",
"created_at":"2014-06-07 07:52:12",  
"updated_at":"2014-06-07 07:52:12"}"
  }
  [1]=>
 array(1) {
   ["answer"]=>
    string(218) "{"id":"20","question_id":"10","answer_text":"Please note that we also maintain the following pages and support forums to help you:",  
"iscorrect":"1",
"created_at":"2014-06-07 07:52:13",  
"updated_at":"2014-06-07 07:52:13"}"
 }
[2]=>
array(1) {
  ["answer"]=>
  string(218) "{"id":"21","question_id":"10",  
  "answer_text":"Please note that we also maintain the following pages and support forums to help you:","iscorrect":"0","created_at":"2014-06-07 07:52:13","updated_at":"2014-06-07 07:52:13"}"
}
}

{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Illegal string offset     'id'","file":"\/home\/learnomatics\/laravel\/mobillz_mlmalp\/app\/controllers\/QuizController.php","line":379}}
```

I am trying to get the values like

```
$answers=Input::get('answers');
var_dump($answers);
foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    if(isset($answer['answer'])){
        quiz_que_ans_id=$answer['answer']['id'];
}
}
```

Comment: You need to decode json string to access values from that string.

Comment: What are you getting in $answer?? Do print_r($answer)..

Comment: I am new to laravel so can u please tell me how to decode json? which method is used?

Comment: You don't need Laravel to decode JSON, just use `json_decode()`.

Comment: Array
(
    [answer] => {"id":"19","question_id":"10","answer_text":"Please note that we also maintain the following pages and support forums to help you:","iscorrect":"1","created_at":"2014-06-07 07:52:12","updated_at":"2014-06-07 07:52:12"}
)
I got this after print_r($answer);

Comment: `$decoded = json_decode($answer['answer']); quiz_que_ans_id=$decoded['id'];`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$answer['answer']` variable is a string comprising JSON encoded data; to access that, you need to decode it first:

```
$data = json_decode($answer['answer'], true);
$quiz_queue_ans_id = $data['id']; // work with decoded data
```

Answer (score 1):

Here your answer contains a json string. Decode it before fetching any key.
Try this :

```
foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    if(isset($answer['answer'])){
        $ans = json_decode($answer['answer'],true);
        if(is_array($ans)){
            quiz_que_ans_id=$ans['id']; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not giving error but not taking values also. means each time showing values=null

Comment: It is not returning array. If i check if(is_array) it returns false. without checking this condition it is working

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, which passes the photo into the `Form::file` facade.

```
{!! Form::file('photo', $user_master->photo, ['class' => 'control-label input-sm', 'type'=>'file', 'accept'=>'image/*']) !!}
```

Instead of

```
{!! Form::file('photo', null, ['class' => 'control-label input-sm', 'type'=>'file', 'accept'=>'image/*']) !!}`
```